# Android switch by values from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new with Android and want to understand another one moment. I've got a strings.xml, which values I use in activity.xml. How use this values from JAva code in switch block?

```
private void gotoActivity(CharSequence text) {
    switch (text.toString()) {
        case getString(R.string.title_activity_first):
            break;

        case RADIO_BUTTON_SECCOND:
            break;
    }
}
```

Not compiles 'cos of "Constant expression required". But the main benefit of strings.xml - is string constants in one place.

Help plz.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the String value obtained from Strings.xml ?

Comment: `getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_first)` instead of just using `getString(R.string.title_activity_first)`.

Comment: `getString` will return different values if you have multiple `strings.xml` files. So it can't be considered as a Constant expression.

Comment: how can we have `multiple` `strings.xml` in same `vlaues` folder.

Comment: @jackjay you can't, but you can have multiple values folders - its the basis for resource localization. bottom line you can't treat these values as "constants" because they aren't.

Comment: @trooper multiple folders having name as `values` in same directory is possible?

Comment: @jackjay I must not be following the discussion very well - maybe there are some deleted comments? you may find the documentation an interesting read. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html .. for example `values` (defaults), `values-en` (english), and `values-en-rIN` (indian english).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use resource string in switch-case. You have two options. Choose anyone...

1. use  `static final String` in your activity.

   **Example:** Initialize the strings

   `public static final String TITLE_ACTIVITY_FIRST = "activity_title";`

   `public static final String RADIO_BUTTON_SECCOND = "radio_button_second";`

   Then you can use the `TITLE_ACTIVITY_FIRST` in switch case. like,

   ```
    switch(text.toString()){
     case TITLE_ACTIVITY_FIRST: break;
     case RADIO_BUTTON_SECOND: break;
      }
   ```

   No error will show!
2. use if-else. You can then use your resource strings.

   **Example:**

   `if(text.toString().equals(getString(R.string.title_activity_first))){
           //your code in case of 1st condition
    }else if(text.toString().equals(getString(R.string.title_activity_second))){
           //your code in case of 2nd condition
   }`

The second might look clumsy. But you wont have to change your code too much. Whereas the first one might look quite handy and you can easily modify later. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah man. Thanks. I know other ways but this seems more intuitive one. Bad bad switch in Java :(

Comment: Glad it helped! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `getString(R.string.title_activity_first)` since it returns  a localised string from the application's package's default string table.So the result will be different based on the locale and hence it won't be a constant.You can not even get a particular local string using  getString() method.Better to use a static final String filed instead.Please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29)